# C++ build process issue with ld: library not found for -lpng

Tags: c++, image-processing, png, libpng

I've tried to run build process my C++ files via `make -j4` but encountered `ld: library not found for -lpng` error.

Here is detailed error:

```
c++  ./framework/CFramework.o ./framework/libparser.o ./framework/CHistogram.o ./framework/CImage.o ./framework/CInspector.o ./framework/framework.o ./framework/operations.o ./curve_filter.o ./algo.o -lpng -lm -lfftw3f -lfftw3f_threads -lgomp -o ponomarenko
ld: library not found for -lpng
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ponomarenko] Error 1
```

Anyone help from folks here is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have libpng installed?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes it is already installed via brew on my macOS. It is in the following path `/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/libpng` 
`/usr/local/opt/libpng` `/usr/local/Cellar/libpng`

Comment: Maybe it is not in the library search path of the linker. Did you write the Makefile yourself or do you use a build system like e.g. cmake?

Comment: @JakobStark it is from Makefile and it is like this `LDFLAGS   = -lpng -lm -lfftw3f -lfftw3f_threads -lgomp`